# Как использовать webp, а для safari jpeg2000

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, webp

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы по дефолту у меня использовалась картинка в формате webp, а для safari подставлялась jpeg2000, хотел сделать через тег picture и srcset, но не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы код понимал, какой браузер используется. Есть способ, чтобы html понимал в каком браузере запускается и как указать это?

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/about-img.webp">
  <img src="img/about-img.jpg" alt="photo">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

Браузер рассмотрит каждый `<source>` и выберет совместимое и наиболее подходящее изображение. Если браузер не поддерживает MIME-тип, указанный в атрибуте `type`, то `<source>` пропускается. [Подробнее...](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/about-img.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img/about-img.jpg" type="image/jp2">
  <img src="img/about-img.jpg" alt="photo">
</picture>
```

Comment: Сделал все так, все равно подставляет img, пропуская source, в яндексе и в хроме одинаково

Comment: А нет, все работает, пришлось галп перезапустить)

Comment: А каким образом можно реализовать такой же функционал, но для бэкграундов в css?

Comment: @Илья Нативно никак, сперва можно протестировать возможности браузера и добавить css-классы — см., например, [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/), или на стороне сервера определять по user agent, в каком формате отдавать картинку

Comment: @Илья в css есть функция image-set для background-image, но поддержка форматов изображений пока работает только в firefox. Синтаксис аналогичен picture srcset.